# Unresolved External After Project Migration

Tags: c++builder, vcl, unresolved-external

I'm using **C++Builder 10.4.1**. I've migrated a simple project containing 3 forms. The main form contains a `TDriveComboBox`. When I try to compile I get these errors:

```
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'Vcl::Filectrl::TDriveComboBox::' referenced from (then it lists the path to the main form's OBJ file)
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '__fastcall Vcl::Filectrl::TDriveComboBox::GetDrive()' referenced from (then it lists the path to the main form's OBJ file)
```

I've even tried to delete the `TDriveComboBox` and replace it, but that doesn't help.
What's the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: You're missing whatever library contains that control from the linker's library list. Deleting the control and adding it back won't help; you still need for the linker to find the library to resolve the symbol before you can build your app.

Comment: @KenWhite no he is not missing anything... its a rare but known problem with project file corruption by IDE

Comment: It is rarely a good idea to let a newer IDE *migrate* an older project. Too many things can go wrong, references can get screwed up, etc.  It is generally best to create a new project fresh in the new IDE and then add your existing source files to that project as needed.

Comment: Remy, I did do a true migration of the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would:

1. delete all temp files (obj,exe,tds,...)
2. add new temp `TDriveComboBox` on form with this problem
3. compile and run.

If that does not help then sometimes manually `#include` VCL header containing the component into form `*.h` file helps reset the compiler/linker so search the VCL inc folder for `TDriveComboBox` In mine system its in here:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\BDS\4.0\include\vcl\FileCtrl.hpp
```

So add something like:

```
#include <FileCtrl.hpp>
```

or

```
#include <vcl\\FileCtrl.hpp>
```

into your form `*.h` file... but even this sometimes fail. **In my experience the problem lies in the project file** (`*.bds, *.bdsproj, ...` or whatever extention the newer versions got) so its a good idea to backup it while the compiler works as should... As **it sometimes corrupt it self** especially for big projects.

Sometimes also helps if you move:

```
#pragma hdrstop
```

line to different locations (few lines down or up). If you're lucky it can also reset the compiler/linker after which you can move it to original location. However this helps only occasionally (like 1:20). And you also need to try few locations

**In case nothing works** just create new empty project and copy the forms and stuff into it and add it to project... Each form has 3 files (`*.h,*.cpp,*.dfm`) and do not forget to add to your project whatever you need (DLL *.lib,...) if its not linked directly with `#pragma link` for all the 3th party custom stuff your app uses

Once (also after migration from BCB5 to BDS2006) even this did not help for one of mine projects. I was forced to create also the forms (with all the components but without functionality just place them on forms) and then copy the stuff from old App... However if you got too many components it will be a pain in the ...

Comment: Thanks. TDriveComboBox is in Vcl.FileCtrl.hpp in C++Builder 10.4.1. Putting an #include in either the compiler-controlled section of the .h file or near the top of the .cpp file works. The format I used is #include <Vcl.FileCtrl.hpp>. I don't like to tamper with the compiler-controlled parts of the .h file, so I put it in the .cpp file.That worked. It's interesting that adding another TDriveComboBox to the form did not cause the #include line to be added to the .h file.

Comment: @BobPenoyer the VCL header structure is generated by the IDE and sometimes it corrupts itself ... manually adding header to the right place will remedy (but not repair) however the project file sometimes reset itself but once something like this occurs it has the tendency to corrupt itself in the same way latter on over and over ... In my experience the more VCL components you got (type and number) the higher probability of this problem... I encountered this on only 3 projects of mine (in over 15 years of BCB coding) so luckily this bug is rare ...

Comment: Also If this solved your problem you should check it as accepted answer. Interesting that on your compiler it needs to be in *.cpp ... I am on older version (BDS2006) and only placing in *.h works so there might be some major changes in the behavior between versions of IDE/compiler

Comment: Adding #include <Vcl.FileCtrl.hpp> in the cpp file works for me migrating from BCB 6 to RAD Studio 11.2. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have found for most of these problems created by the ide in converting my 10.3.3 projects to 10.4.1 can be solved by an annoying process as described below:

1. open the form.
2. on design tab, switch to text view.
3. switch to form veiw.
4. under project, recompile just the form.
5. now run project.

This has solved most of my unresolved's except _CG_*.